# Saving datetime to database in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to update the lastsync column the problem is the data wont save properly. I used **Convert.ToDateTime** and **DateTime.Parse** and still the data wont save properly. I am getting **"01/01/0001 12:00:00"**. What am I doing wrong?

```
public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }

var current_datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

string ofretailer_group_sql = "UPDATE tblRetailerGroup SET LastUpdated = '" + DateTime.Parse(current_datetime) + "' WHERE RetailerCode = '" + retailerCode + "'";
await conn.ExecuteAsync(ofretailer_group_sql);
```

Comment: What is the field type of `LastUpdated`?

Comment: public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }

Comment: @SushiHangover how can I fix this?

Comment: I would actually save the date and time as a Unix timestamp (of type UInt32).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting `01/01/0001 12:00:00` from your TimeDate field, that means it was never set/updated.

Personally I use query (`?`) parameters to allow the SQL statement strings to become a bunch of constants that never change and then you just have to assign the parameters for that query in the order they fall within the SQL statement:

#### Example:

```
const string ofretailer_group_sql = "UPDATE tblRetailerGroup SET LastUpdated = ? WHERE RetailerCode = ?";

await conn.ExecuteAsync(ofretailer_group_sql, new object[] { DateTime.UtcNow, retailerCode });
```

Note: I am using `UtcNow` to remove DST and phone device timezone change issues...

Comment: Question DateTime.UtcNow's time zone is based on the location of the phone?

Comment: No time zone/No day light saving:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time

Answer (score 0):

You should create dependency services for file management to save and get a data in IOS and Android level. Here is code how to save and get datetime in file.

PCL Project:- Create the interface

```
public interface IFileHelper
{

    void SaveLastUpdatedDateTimeForData(DateTime dateTime);

    DateTime GetLastUpdatedDateTimeForData();

}
```

IOS/Android Project:- Create one Class to save the data in file.

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(FileHelper))]
namespace ABCD.iOS 
{
 public class FileHelper: IFileHelper 
{

  public void SaveLastUpdatedDateTimeForData(DateTime dateTime) 
{
   try {
    string docFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    string filePath = Path.Combine(docFolder, "..", "Library", "updatetime.txt");
    File.WriteAllText(filePath, dateTime.Ticks.ToString());
   } catch (Exception ex) {
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
   }


  }

  public DateTime GetLastUpdatedDateTimeForData() 
{
   //bool status = false;
   string docFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
   string filePath = Path.Combine(docFolder, "..", "Library", "updatetime.txt");
   if (!File.Exists(filePath)) {
    return new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);
   }

   try {
    string content = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(long.Parse(content));
    return dt;
   } catch (Exception ex) {
    Debug.WriteLine("exception in GetLastUpdatedDateTimeForData : {0}", ex.Message);
    return DateTime.MinValue;
   }
  }

 }
}
```

Call the dependency Service in Client/PCL project:

Save updated DateTime:

```
DependencyService.Get<IFileHelper>().SaveLastUpdatedDateTimeForData(DateTime.Now);
```

Get Updated DateTime:

```
var lastUpdatedDateTime = DependencyService.Get<IFileHelper>().GetLastUpdatedDateTimeForData();
```

Comment: No need for that I just need to fix how I update my data

Comment: try to use string datatype instead of Datetime

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a conversion issue from Date-String-Date.

I would go for directly saving first DateTime.now in Db and check if the value is saved correctly. If that works then definitely its a conversion issue. Then you can try below solution.

I do conversion like this:

DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(current_datetime, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);